# Common vectors of a matrix and its orthogonal compliment

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say that we have $W$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Would $W$ and $W^⊥$ have any vectors in common?

Answer (score 4):

$W$ and $W^{\perp}$ only have the zero in common, because if $y\in W\cap W^{\perp}$, then $y$ is orthogonal to itself.